# How to use Jane Street's Core with Reason?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, reason

I'm new to OCaml and I'm trying to try (:P) Facebook Reason syntax. I cannot find a way to make this compile because if cannot find the Core module (already installed with opam).

I'm trying to compile a sample program from Real World OCaml

```
open Core.Std;

let rec read_and_accumulate accum => {
  let line = In_channel.input_line In_channel.stdin;
  switch line {
    | None => accum
    | Some x => read_and_accumulate (accum +. Float.of_string x)
  }
};

let () = printf "Total: %F\n" (read_and_accumulate 0.);
```

This is the command I'm using for compilation: `rebuild accum.native`.

When I have this in `_tags` (from the instructions in https://janestreet.github.io/installation.html)

```
true: package(core,ppx_jane)
true: thread,debug
```

My error changes but I still don't know what to do:

```
File "_tags", line 1, characters 6-28:
Warning: tag "package" does not expect a parameter, but is used with parameter "core,ppx_jane"
File "_tags", line 1, characters 6-28:
Warning: the tag "package(core,ppx_jane)" is not used in any flag or dependency declaration, so it will have no effect; it may be a typo. Otherwise you can use `mark_tag_used` in your myocamlbuild.ml to disable this warning.
+ /Users/David/.opam/4.02.3/bin/ocamldep.opt -modules -pp refmt -impl accum2.re | tee accum2.re.depends accum2.ml.depends
accum2.re: Core Float In_channel
+ /Users/David/.opam/4.02.3/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -g -thread -pp '-g -thread' -pp refmt -o accum2.cmo -intf-suffix .rei -impl accum2.re
File "accum2.re", line 1, characters 5-13:
Error: Unbound module Core
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 2 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

What do I have to do to use Core with Reason?

Adopting the syntax is pretty easy and I have only been reading for a couple hours, but there's zero docs about how to use Reason for non OCaml users.

Comment: Have you achieved compilation since asking this question? I'm currently struggling with the same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Still stuck with the same step. Without deeper knowledge into OCaml tooling it's impossible. This has something to do with what rebuild that but it's a bash script doing many things around ocamlbuild so I have not idea what most of the output even means. :(

Answer (score 3):

Basically the tags indicated in https://janestreet.github.io/installation.html have to be added *plus* three more flags and values used for this case:

- `-linkpkg` for static linking I assume
- `-pp refmt` indicating the ReasonML preprocessor
- `-impl file.re` to tell what file to read

So if the file's called `accum.re` it can be compiled to a native binary with:

`ocamlfind ocamlc -g -thread -package ppx_jane -package core -pp refmt -linkpkg -o accum.native -impl accum.re`

Answer (score 3):

It seems there has been a recent [bug fix](https://github.com/facebook/reason/commit/7c07ce4d4cec57924b2c6b49eea5b6f106842176) of the issue in the Reason repo. Basically, since `rebuild` turns out to be a wrapper around `reasonbuild` it's possible to work around the bug by running `reasonbuild` directly:

```sh
env OCAMLFIND_COMMANDS="ocamlc=$(which reopt)" reasonbuild -use-ocamlfind accum.native
```

In fact, `reasonbuild -use-ocamlfind accum.native` also works here.

Comment: is this from head? or is this in stable? In 0.6 I think it still doesn't work

Comment: From the GitHub repo it seems this is currently only in master, it's possible to install reason from this commit with OPAM, e.g. `opam pin add -y  reason 'https://github.com/facebook/reason.git#44aa9f4695e14c247c29c4fbc98ca10dcf332eab'`, but as this is not a release this is probably not recommended

Answer (score 0):

I guess `rebuild` is a wrapper around ocamlbuild. Just call it with the parameter `-use-ocamlfind`.

Comment: That's indeed what I think it's but it's hardly a solution. If you could help with real indications that would be much appreciated. I tried with `-pkg core` also using `-use-ocamlfind` without any luck.